# Вывести на экран данные с#

Tags: c#

Вывести на экран

5

5 4

5 4 3

5 4 3 2

5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Как пытались решить задачу?

Comment: запутался в циклах чет,поэтому прошу тут решить

Comment: Так покажите ваш код и где он не работает

Comment: тут в принципе достаточно одного цикла

Comment: `поэтому прошу тут решить` - тут не решают за кого-то, тут помогают. Если вы не покажите что у вас в намётках есть, что пытались, то очень велика вероятность, что вопрос заминусют и закроют

Comment: полная дичь конечно но вот нашел код   for(int al = 1; al == 5; al++)
            {
                Console.Write(al);
                for (int t= 4; t == 0; t--)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t);
                }

            }

Comment: Это неправильно. Надо хотя бы for(int al = 5; al >0; al--) { Console.Write(al); for (int t= 5; t >= a; t--) { Console.Write(t); }Console.WriteLine; } –

Answer (score 4):

Вариант через 1 цикл:

- Заводишь строковую переменную, инициализированную пустой строкой.
- Делаешь цикл не восходящий от 0 до 5, а нисходяший от 5 до 0 (0 не включая) с шагом 1
- На каждой итерации к строковой переменной конкатинируешь число (счетчик в цикле) 
  и пробел.
- Конкатенированную строку выводишь через `WriteLine`

Comment: конкатенируешь лучше